# C# Automapper DTO with nested dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I want to have a ProductDetailedReadDto with nested CategoryReadDto.

ProductDetailedReadDto:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Categories.Dtos;

  public class ProductDetailedReadDto
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public CategoryReadDto Category { get; set; }
  }
```

CategoryReadDto:

```
using System;


  public class CategoryReadDto
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
  }
```

ProductsProfile:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Products.Dtos;
using Products.Models;

  public class ProductsProfile : Profile
  {
    public ProductsProfile()
    {
      // source -> target
      CreateMap<Product, ProductDetailedReadDto>();

      // CreateMap<Product, ProductDetailedReadDto>().ForMember(dst => dst.Category, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Category));
    }
  }
```

Product Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Categories.Models;
using ProductImages.Models;
using Reviews.Models;

  public class Product
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
  }
```

Category Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Products.Models;

  public class Category
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }


  }
```

Controller Code:

```
  [HttpGet("detailed")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductDetailedReadDto>> GetAllProductsDetailed()
    {
      var productModelFromRepo = _repository.Products.GetAllProductsDetailed();
      return Ok(_mapper.Map<ProductDetailedReadDto>(productModelFromRepo));
    }
```

The error I get is this below and I can not understand why. Even if I uncomment the code with the forMember and link the Category property in the ProductProfile.

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Object -> ProductDetailedReadDto
System.Object -> Products.Dtos.ProductDetailedReadDto
   at lambda_method240(Closure , Object , ProductDetailedReadDto , ResolutionContext )
   at Eshop.Controllers.ProductsController.GetAllProductsDetailed() in C:\Users\anton\Desktop\projects\Backend\antonis-personal\Eshop\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: `Map<<IEnumerable<ProductDetailedReadDto>>`

Comment: Yeah that was the issue but I could not figure out from the error. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

As Lucian Bargaoanu pointed out I should add this in the controller

```
Map<<IEnumerable<ProductDetailedReadDto>>
```